# Are topics in Google's cloud pub/sub case-sensitive?

Tags: case-sensitive, case-insensitive, google-cloud-pubsub

Simple question. Is

```
 projects/myproject/topics/mytopic
```

The different from

```
 projects/myproject/topics/MyTopic
```

MQTT are case-sensitive according to [this](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/):

> Noticeable is that each topic must have at least 1 character to be valid and it can also contain spaces. Also a topic is case-sensitive, which makes myhome/temperature and MyHome/Temperature two individual topics. Additionally the forward slash alone is a valid topic, too.

But surprisingly I cannot find any information official or otherwise for Google's cloud pubsub

Answer (score 0):

Yes, topics and subscriptions are all case sensitive.

Comment: just based on experience or can you point to some documentation?